# discrete approximations of partial derivatives

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, finite-differences

i'm reading a paper *Polynomial Shape from Shading* about the SFS problem.
And it's written in this paper as the following:
[the discrete partial derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVtp5.png).

it makes me confused since we know that:
$$\begin{align}&\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\approx \frac{f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y)}{\delta x},\\&\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\approx \frac{f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)}{\delta y}.\end{align}$$
So i searched its references and found that in *Shape from shading using linear approximation*: [discrete approximations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCw14.png) .

My problem is: why don't the formulas in these two paper divide by $\delta x$ or $\delta y$? Since
it's pixel coordinates?

Comment: $\delta x=\delta y=1$ in that cases, and you don't need to divide.

Comment: @JoséCFerreira thank you!